# Automatically escape unicode characters

Tags: r

How can you display a unicode string, say:

```
x <- "•"
```

using its escaped equivalent?

```
y <- "\u2022"

identical(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
```

(I'd like to be able to do this because CRAN packages must contain only ASCII, but sometimes you want to use unicode in an error message or similar)

Comment: It is strange because I tested your `identical(x, y)` on different machines and the results are not invariable. Using the function `stri_escape_unicode` in the answer: `stri_escape_unicode(x)` on a Windows machine  yields `"\\u0095"`. EDIT: well, it has something to do with the encoding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After digging into some documentation about `iconv`, I think you can accomplish this using only the `base` package. But you need to pay extra attention to the encoding of the string.

On a system with UTF-8 encoding:

```
> stri_escape_unicode("你好世界")
[1] "\\u4f60\\u597d\\u4e16\\u754c"

# use big endian
> iconv(x, "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE", toRaw=T)
[[1]]
[1] 4f 60 59 7d 4e 16 75 4c

> x <- "•"
> iconv(x, "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE", toRaw=T)    
[[1]]
[1] 20 22
```

But, if you are on a system with `latin1` encoding, things may go wrong.

```
> x <- "•"
> y <- "\u2022"
> identical(x, y)
[1] FALSE
> stri_escape_unicode(x)
[1] "\\u0095" # <- oops!

# culprit
> Encoding(x)
[1] "latin1"

# and it causes problem for iconv
> iconv(x, Encoding(x), "Unicode")
Error in iconv(x, Encoding(x), "Unicode") : 
  unsupported conversion from 'latin1' to 'Unicode' in codepage 1252
> iconv(x, Encoding(x), "UTF-16BE")
Error in iconv(x, Encoding(x), "UTF-16BE") : 
  embedded nul in string: '\0•'
```

It is safer to cast the string into UTF-8 before converting to Unicode:

```
> iconv(enc2utf8(enc2native(x)), "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE", toRaw=T)
[[1]]
[1] 20 22
```

**EDIT: This may cause some problems for strings already in UTF-8 encoding on some particular systems. Maybe it's safer to check the encoding before conversion.**

```
> Encoding("•")
[1] "latin1"
> enc2native("•")
[1] "•"
> enc2native("\u2022")
[1] "•"
# on a Windows with default latin1 encoding
> Encoding("测试") 
[1] "UTF-8"
> enc2native("测试") 
[1] "<U+6D4B><U+8BD5>"   # <- BAD!
```

For some characters or lanuages, `UTF-16` may not be enough. So probably you should be using `UTF-32` since

> The UTF-32 form of a character is a direct representation of its codepoint.

Based on above trial and error, below is probably one safer escape function we can write:

```
unicode_escape <- function(x, endian="big") {
  if (Encoding(x) != 'UTF-8') {
    x <- enc2utf8(enc2native(x))
  }
  to.enc <- ifelse(endian == 'big', 'UTF-32BE', 'UTF-32LE')

  bytes <- strtoi(unlist(iconv(x, "UTF-8", "UTF-32BE", toRaw=T)), base=16)
  # there may be some better way to do thibs.
  runes <- matrix(bytes, nrow=4)
  escaped <- apply(runes, 2, function(rb) {
    nonzero.bytes <- rb[rb > 0]
    ifelse(length(nonzero.bytes) > 1, 
           # convert back to hex
           paste("\\u", paste(as.hexmode(nonzero.bytes), collapse=""), sep=""),
           rawToChar(as.raw(nonzero.bytes))
           )
  })
  paste(escaped, collapse="")
}
```

#### Tests:

```
> unicode_escape("•••ERROR!!!•••")
[1] "\\u2022\\u2022\\u2022ERROR!!!\\u2022\\u2022\\u2022"
> unicode_escape("Hello word! 你好世界！")
[1] "Hello word! \\u4f60\\u597d\\u4e16\\u754c!"
> "\u4f60\u597d\u4e16\u754c"
[1] "你好世界"
```

Comment: It isn't, but `iconv` is. The other answer used `stri_escape_unicode` and I'm just trying to show that you don't have to use `stri_escape_unicode`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the exploration with base R

Comment: This function fails for some inputs. For example, `"\u00e9"` ("é") is not ASCII but passes through without being encoded. `"\u0200"` ("Ȁ") becomes `"\002"` (control code: start of text). Also: `"\u0404"` ("Є") -> `"\\u44"` ("D"), `"\U0001f600"` (grinning face) -> `"\\u01f6"` ("Ƕ"), `"\u040413"` (`"\u0404"` followed by `"13"`) -> `"\\u4413"` ("䐓"), and `"\U0001f601"` (grinning face with smiling eyes) -> `"\\u01f601"` ("Ƕ01").

Answer (score 7):

The package `stringi` has a method for doing this

```
stri_escape_unicode(y)
# [1] "\\u2022"
```

Comment: Should've known that `stringi` would have a function for this!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small package called `uniscape` that can convert non-ASCII characters to the corresponding `"\u1234"` or `"\U12345678"` Unicode escape codes (obviously with a literal backslash). It can do so for any character or only for characters inside an R string (single or double quoted). The following example shows how `u_escape` converts a character. The output is then surrounded with quotes, parsed, and evaluated. The final result matches the original character.

```
x <- rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xe2, 0x80, 0xa2)))
Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
x
# [1] "•"
x_u <- uniscape::u_escape(x)
x_u
# [1] "\\u2022"
y <- eval(parse(text = paste0('"', x_u, '"')))
y
# [1] "•"
identical(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
```

The package (on [GitHub](https://github.com/mvkorpel/uniscape)) also provides RStudio addins for convenience. The addins operate on the active source editor document. The package has no hard dependencies except `rstudioapi`.

This picture shows an example document with a selected text area and the RStudio addin window with three `uniscape` addins. "Escape selection" addin has been selected.
[image: Example document and addin window]

This is the result after applying "Escape selection", with the encoding sequence of *each non-ASCII character* automatically highlighted (selected).
[image: Result of Escape selection addin]

After undoing the previous operation, this is the result for "Escape strings in file". Each affected *R string* in the active file is automatically highlighted by the addin. Commented strings are ignored. "Escape selected strings" does the same but only for the selected text area.
[image: Result of Escape strings in file]

Answer (score 1):

R automatically escapes unicode in C locale:

```r
x <- "•"
Sys.setlocale(locale = 'C')
print(x)
# [1] "<U+2022>"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on windows